# retrieve an arbitrary frame from a video on android

Tags: android, video

Android's MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail allows you to get the first frame of a video as a thumbnail. Is it possible to obtain other thumbnails besides the first frame? (perhaps there is there a way to modify a file descriptor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API is available through the honeycomb android 3.0 API

Answer (score 0):

I use FFmpeg to do this using the Android NDK which should work for non-honeycomb devices.